# XML Parsing Error while Upgrading Custom Module

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

I'm new in Odoo. Created a simple custom module. It was working fine till when I've splitted xml file into two. Its giving below error while trying to upgrade my custom module:

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Odoo\Odoo_15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 643, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "D:\Odoo\Odoo_15\odoo\odoo\http.py", line 301, in _handle_exception
    raise exception.with_traceback(None) from new_cause
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: while parsing file:/d:/odoo/odoo_15/custom_addons/om_hospital/views/menu.xml:17, somewhere inside
<menuitem id="menu_patient" name="Patient" action="action_hospital_patient" parent="menu_patient_master" sequence="0"/>
```

Here are codes:

**manifest**.py:

```
{
    'name': 'Custom Hospital Management by Milon',
    'version': '1.0.0',
    'category': 'Hospital Maanagement',
    'author': 'Milon Sarker',
    'summary': 'Its a custom system',
    'description': 'Its a custom system bro',
    'depends': [],
    'data': [
        'views/menu.xml',
        'views/patient_view.xml',
    ],
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': False,
    'application': True,
    'sequence': -100
}
```

model : patient.py:

```
from odoo import api, fields, models

class hospitalPatient(models.Model):
    _name = 'hospital.patient'
    _description = 'Hospital Patient'
    name = fields.Char(string = 'Name')
    age = fields.Integer(string = "Age")
    gender = fields.Selection([('male','Male'), ('female', 'Female')], string = "Gender")
```

menu.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <menuitem id = "menu_hospital_root"
              name = "Hospital"
              sequence = "0"
    />
    <menuitem id = "menu_patient_master"
              name = "Patient Details"
              parent = "menu_hospital_root"
              sequence = "0"
    />
    <menuitem id="menu_patient"
              name="Patient"
              action="action_hospital_patient"
              parent="menu_patient_master"
              sequence="0"
    />
</odoo>
```

patient_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<odoo>
    <record id = "action_hospital_patient" model = "ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Patients</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">hospital.patient</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form,</field>
        <field name="context">{}</field>
        <field name="help" type = "html">
            <p class = "o_view_nocontent_smiling_face">
                Create your first patient!
            </p>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [menuitem](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/master/developer/reference/backend/data.html#menuitem) documentation:

> action
> if specified, the action attribute should be the external id of an action to execute when the menu is open.

Use the external id in the last menu item for the `action`:

```xml
om_hospital.action_hospital_patient
```

When loading the menu item, odoo will try to get the [action database id](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/odoo/tools/convert.py#L459) if the action is set and valid.

You should load the `menu.xml` after the `patient_view.xml`, update the `data` entry in the manifest file to the following:

```
'data': [
    'views/patient_view.xml',
    'views/menu.xml',
],
```

Comment: which name is module name? folder name or name in __manifest__.py file?

Comment: The folder name

Comment: thanks but not solved. same error.  changed like this : `action="om_hospital.action_hospital_patient"`

Comment: Did you change the file order in the manifest file?

Comment: hey @kenly, thanks a lot... Now I changed the order in manifest file like this: `    'data': [
        'views/patient_view.xml',
        'views/menu.xml',
    ],` and its working... so simple error got my 4-5 hours...any reference on this issue. how should serialize this?

Comment: if you kindly change the answer a little bit... i can accept your answer. thanks.

Comment: I updated the answer to highlight the two issues and feel free to edit if needed

Comment: I've accepeted your answer... however, I'm not 100% clear about the concept here. Is it that I'm using a action without defining it first? @Kenly . Thanks for your help. Would love to connect with you.

Comment: Odoo will use the action database id (we use the external id to refer to a record without knowing its database ID ), this is why we need to import the action before the menu item.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I don't know the root cause of the issue but here is my workaround below:

1. In the **manifest**.py, rearrange the data sequence:

```html
'data':[
        'security/ir.model.access.csv',
         # Define action in patient views before their references
        'views/patient_view.xml',
        'views/menu.xml', # Last because referencing actions defined in previous files
    ],
```

2. Go to Settings -> Technical -> Actions (not Windows Actions). Find "Patients" and then Delete it.
3. Go to Apps. Find your module (in this case Hospital Management) and then Upgrade.
   Done. It's working as expected. Hope this works for you!

P/s: Maybe we are facing this issue because we already created the Action "action_hospital_patient" following the tutorial video "5. How To Create Window Action In Odoo || Actions In Odoo - [https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcVMcJYHuzc&list=PLqRRLx0cl0homY1elJbSoWfeQbRKJ-oPO&index=5"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XcVMcJYHuzc&list=PLqRRLx0cl0homY1elJbSoWfeQbRKJ-oPO&index=5%22)